# What would Negamax' initial function call look like were it to minimize root node rather than maximize?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, minimax, negamax, tree-search

Negamax typically looks like the below:

```
function negamax(node, depth, α, β, color) is
    if depth = 0 or node is a terminal node then
        return color × the heuristic value of node
    childNodes := generateMoves(node)
    childNodes := orderMoves(childNodes)
    value := −∞
    foreach child in childNodes do
        value := max(value, −negamax(child, depth − 1, −β, −α, −color))
        α := max(α, value)
        if α ≥ β then
            break (* cut-off *)
    return value
```

And the initial call is `negamax(rootNode, depth, −∞, +∞, 1)` if the maximizing player called it.

I've implemented Negamax in a way where the maximizing player calls it, but each `rootNode` is one of the maximizing players moves:

```
function negamaxHandler() is
    bestValue := −∞
    bestNode := null
    childNodes := generateMoves(currentGameState)
    foreach child in childNodes do
        value := negamax(child, depth-1, ???, ???, ???)
        if value > bestValue then
            bestValue := value
            bestNode := child
    return bestNode
```

Because Negamax returns a value, I instead want a board state (move). So I do the first level of Negamax manually so I can parse where the best move is. But for what values should I call `negamax` on? To be more declarative, if maximizing player called `negamaxHandler`, should `negamaxHandler` call:

```
negamax(child, depth-1, −∞, +∞, 1)
-negamax(child, depth-1, −∞, +∞, 1)
negamax(child, depth-1, +∞, −∞, -1)
-negamax(child, depth-1, +∞, −∞, -1)
```

Or something else? To clarify:

- maximizing player calls `negamaxHandler`
- each top level call to `negamax` in `negamaxHandler` should minimize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct function call ended up being `-negamax(child, depth-1, −∞, +∞, -1)`, although the `negamaxHandler` function needed to be changed:

```
function negamaxHandler(α, β, color) is
    bestValue := −∞
    bestNode := null
    childNodes := generateMoves(currentGameState)
    foreach child in childNodes do
        value := -negamax(child, depth-1, -β, -α, -color)
        if value > bestValue then
            bestValue := value
            bestNode := child
        α := max(bestValue, α)
        if α ≥ β then
           break
    return bestNode
```

With `negamaxHandler` being called as `negamaxHandler(−∞, +∞, 1)`.